# Conditional assignment in c++ opencv

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, multidimensional-array

In Python with opencv/numpy (2D) arrays `A1, A2, B1, B2` I can do

```
A1[B1>B2] = A2[B1>B2]
```

That is, I can assign values to A1 from A2 in places based on a condition between the B arrays.

How can I do this in opencv in C++?
Is the fastest way to simply loop over the arrays, or is there a better way?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mask.

```
Mat m=B1>B2;
A2.copyTo(A1,m);
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks!